# Create An Optgroup from an Array of data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter to query my database and return an array of data.

I have got an array of data like so :

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [depot_id] => 1
        [depot_name] => Stockton On Tees
        [depot_description] => Arriva Stockton on Tees Depot
        [depot_postcode] => TS18 3AW
        [depot_lat] => 
        [depot_long] => 
        [operating_company_id] => 1
        [date_created] => 2014-02-14 10:24:17
        [date_edited] => 
        [edited_by] => 
        [status] => active
        [operating_company_name] => Arriva North East
        [operating_company_description] => Arriva North East
        [operating_company_lat] => 
        [operating_company_long] => 
        [operating_company_postcode] => 
        [operating_group_id] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [depot_id] => 2
        [depot_name] => Darlington
        [depot_description] => Arriva Darlington Depot
        [depot_postcode] => DH1 1TW
        [depot_lat] => 
        [depot_long] => 
        [operating_company_id] => 1
        [date_created] => 2014-02-14 10:24:17
        [date_edited] => 
        [edited_by] => 
        [status] => active
        [operating_company_name] => Arriva North East
        [operating_company_description] => Arriva North East
        [operating_company_lat] => 
        [operating_company_long] => 
        [operating_company_postcode] => 
        [operating_group_id] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [depot_id] => 3
        [depot_name] => Ashington
        [depot_description] => Arriva Ashington Depot
        [depot_postcode] => NE63 9UN
        [depot_lat] => 
        [depot_long] => 
        [operating_company_id] => 2
        [date_created] => 2014-02-14 10:46:05
        [date_edited] => 
        [edited_by] => 
        [status] => active
        [operating_company_name] => Arriva Northumbria
        [operating_company_description] => Arriva Northumbria
        [operating_company_lat] => 
        [operating_company_long] => 
        [operating_company_postcode] => 
        [operating_group_id] => 1
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [depot_id] => 4
        [depot_name] => Blyth
        [depot_description] => Arriva Blyth Depot
        [depot_postcode] => NE24 2AP
        [depot_lat] => 
        [depot_long] => 
        [operating_company_id] => 2
        [date_created] => 2014-02-14 10:46:05
        [date_edited] => 
        [edited_by] => 
        [status] => active
        [operating_company_name] => Arriva Northumbria
        [operating_company_description] => Arriva Northumbria
        [operating_company_lat] => 
        [operating_company_long] => 
        [operating_company_postcode] => 
        [operating_group_id] => 1
    )
```

I would like to create an optgroup based on the "Operating Company Name" so in this example there are 2 depots that fall underneath it.

In my view, I am current just using a foreach loop to create the dropdown.

```
            <select name="depot_id" class="form-control">
            <?php foreach($depots as $depot): ?>
                    <optgroup label="<?php echo $depot->operating_company_name; ?>">
                        <option value="<?php echo $depot->depot_id; ?>"><?php echo $depot->depot_name; ?></option>
                    </optgroup>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

That is producing an dropdown as follows....

[image: Dropdown Optgroup]

How can I (If possible) in the loop put every operating group and depot together?

Can give my MySQL Query if needed.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll have to use a double foreach loop to create what you're wanting

Comment: try this: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/129610/#639772

Comment: Hi @Newbi3 what am I double looping on though?

Comment: After working through you're problem some. You'll need to loop through once to get the operating names into an array. And build the array using the name as a key. $optgroupArray[$depot->operating_company_name]

Comment: For every match, add the depot to make a 2D array.

Comment: I realize my solution will probably take 3 loops but it would work and not the best efficiency

Comment: Once you create the 2 arrays, you iterate through one last time and echo the optgroup and count the number of elements in your 2D array for that key. You will iterate as many depots as you have to create the correct number of options and repeat for each operating_company_name you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try, first reformat the  source array like below :

```
$result = array();
foreach($depots as $depot){
   $result[$depot->operating_company_name][] = $depot;
}
```

Then for creating the select try,

```
<select name="depot_id" class="form-control">
            <?php foreach($result as $key=>$val): ?>
                    <optgroup label="<?php echo $key; ?>">
                       <?php foreach($val as $option): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $option->depot_id; ?>"><?php echo $option->depot_name; ?></option>
                         <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </optgroup>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Absolutley superb! Thanks for that