# Select option with optgroup from mysql (group car model by class)

Tags: php, mysql

how can I group specific model class to one column? and best if I could be able to click on optgroup name to show all models of this group is it possible at all? Thank you guys.

Example what I need:

```
3 serial
   318
   320
5 serial
   520
   525
```

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT b.model_id, b.model_name, GROUP_CONCAT(b.model_class_name)
            FROM tbl_model b 
            JOIN tbl_car c ON b.model_id = c.model_id 
            JOIN tbl_model_class d ON b.model_id = d.model_id 
            GROUP BY b.model_class_name 
            WHERE b.brand_id=? ORDER BY b.model_name ASC");
$stmt->execute(array($id));
$models = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($models as $model) {
    echo '<optgroup label="'.$model['model_class_name'].'">';
        echo '<option value="'.$model['model_id'].'">'.$model['model_name'].'</option>';
    echo '</optgroup>';
}
```

SQL :

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_brand` (`brand_id`, `brand_name`) VALUES
(8, 'BMW');

INSERT INTO `tbl_model` (`model_id`, `model_name`, `brand_id`) VALUES
(164, '114', 8),
(165, '116', 8),
(166, '118', 8);

INSERT INTO `tbl_model_class` (`model_class_id`, `model_class_name`, `model_id`) VALUES
(1, '1 serial', 164),
(2, '1 serial', 165),
(3, '1 serial', 166);
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create the option group? ... if so, there are many examples here on SO. (as well as other sites across the internet)

Comment: I tried in many ways and fail :D i'm not very good in back end. With this code show only one car in optgroup, other car with same class show not in optgroup ^^

`$str = ''; $outgroup = '';
foreach ($models as $model)
{
 if($outgroup != $model['option_class_type']) {
  $str .= '<optgroup label="'.$model['option_class_type'].'">';
 }
 $str .= '<option value="'.$model['model_id'].'">'.$model['model_name'].'</option>';
 if($outgroup != $model['option_class_type']) {
  $str .= '</optgroup>';
 }
 $outgroup = $model['option_class_type'];
}
echo $str;`

Comment: Try to think about it this way: (how I've done in the past) Try to build an array of arrays to ultimately resemble: `$models['opt_class_type']['model_id, 'model_name']`. Then you could use a nested foreach loop. The outer foreach could be: `foreach ($models as $key => $values)`. The `$key` is used for the `optgroup` value. The inner foreach could be: `foreach ($values as $value)`. Each `$value` is used to build each `option` tag where `$value[0]` is for the `value` attribute and `$value[1]` is the name to display. See the loops in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21877526/7644018)